# For loop not working ffmpeg

Tags: bash, loops

my script is not giving me any output

```
for file in ./*
do
    if [ "$file" = *.mov ];
    then
        ffmpeg -i $file -an -f framemd5
    fi
done
```

whenever I run it it just give me back my prompt immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Because your test:

```
if [ "$file" = *.mov ];
```

is false.

If, for exampe, the current directory has these files:

```
file1.mov
file2
file3.txt
file4.mov
```

Then the `$file` variable will be set as follows through each iteration:

1. `./file1.mov`
2. `./file2`
3. `./file3.txt`
4. `./file4.mov`

But the right-hand side of the test will remain to be "`file1.mov file4.mov`", so each test is:

1. `if [ "./file1.mov" = file1.mov file4.mov];`
2. `if [ "./file2" = file1.mov file4.mov];`
3. `if [ "./file3.txt" = file1.mov file4.mov];`
4. `if [ "./file4.mov" = file1.mov file4.mov];`

...neither of which is ever true.

If you want to loop through all the .mov files in the current directory, use this instead:

```
for file in ./*.mov; do
    ffmpeg -i $file -an -f framemd5
done
```

By the way, you should always be ready for files with spaces and other annoying characters in the name, so this would be a bit more robust:

```
for file in ./*.mov; do
    ffmpeg -i "$file" -an -f framemd5
done
```

As it will put quotes around the file name.

Comment: Thank you, dovetalk. A very helpful answer.

Comment: If I want the script to read not from the current directory I am in but from any directory I place in the CLI, how do I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "in the CLI", but if you want it to be the first parameter to the script, you just change `./*.mov` to `"$1"/*.mov`

Comment: Now what if I the directory chosen as the first parameter has mutiple directories within it, each with with multiple .mov files. How do I write the script to loop through all .mov files within that directory at various depths?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using `bash`, you need to use the `[[` command for pattern matching.

```
for file in ./*
do
    if [[ "$file" = *.mov ]];
    then
        ffmpeg -i "$file" -an -f framemd5
    fi
done
```

However, it's simpler to just match the `.mov` files in the first pattern as shown by dovetalk.

Comment: Thank you, chepner, as well.